# How to customize audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio-player

I'm trying to replicate this audio player:

https://medium.com/s/story/the-law-of-least-effort-is-the-success-secret-nobody-talks-about-c713eeab8ade)

with a grey progress line, but I can't seem to figure out the following 4 things:

1. How to put the progress bar next to the play/pause button?
2. How to have 2 decimals for the total time digit? (The 48 seconds)
3. How to have 2 decimals for the currentTimer? (First 9 seconds)
4. How to place the timers at the beginning and the end?

```js
var barSize = 640;
var bar = document.getElementById('defaultBar');
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

mytrack.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
  var minutes = parseInt(mytrack.duration / 60);
  var seconds = parseInt(mytrack.duration % 60);
  duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
})

duration.innerHTML = mytrack.duration;

playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
bar.addEventListener('click', clickedBar, false);
```

```css
#progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #C6C6C6;
  width: 0px;
  float: left;
}

#playButton {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-image: url(../Desktop/Play%20button.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#player {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <audio id="mytrack">
    <source src="file:///Users/Pier/Desktop/Narrated%20Story%20-%20Example.m4a" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

  <nav>
    <div id="defaultBar">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button type="button" id="playButton"></button>
      <span id="currentTime">0:00</span>
      <span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods of achieving those goals? It might help to show them and let us know what specifically is going wrong. Also, it's difficult to reproduce your situation without a working m4a file.

Comment: Hi showdev, the most important thing I'm trying to fix now is having the progress bar sitting next to the play button instead of above it. I tried to make divs from both elements and to center them in a container but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. Also tried float: left; but not much success yet.

Comment: The total timer is weird; sometimes it shows 0:48 seconds nicely, but most of the times it shows a number like 48.065306

Answer (score 1):

The page you referenced uses [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for layout. You might consider a similar approach.

Below, I restructured your HTML and made each control element a flexbox item.
I also centered all items vertically with `align-items:center`.

```js
var myTrack = document.getElementById('myTrack');
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');
var fullDuration = document.getElementById('fullDuration');

function zeroPad(s) {
  return ('00' + s).slice(-2);
}

function formatTime(t) {
  var m = Math.floor(t / 60);
  var s = Math.floor(t % 60);
  return zeroPad(m) + ':' + zeroPad(s);
}

function playOrPause() {
  myTrack.paused ? myTrack.play() : myTrack.pause();
}

myTrack.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
  fullDuration.innerHTML = formatTime(this.duration);
});

myTrack.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  var thisTime = this.currentTime;
  var duration = this.duration;
  progressBar.style.width = thisTime / duration * 100 + '%';
  currentTime.innerHTML = formatTime(thisTime);
});

playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
```

```css
#audioControls {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.controlTime {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#progressWrap {
  /* Allow this element to grow */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progressBar {
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: #55AA55;
  width: 0;
}

#playButton {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#playButton:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <audio id="myTrack">
    <source src="https://example-files.online-convert.com/audio/m4a/example.m4a" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

  <nav id="audioControls">
    <button type="button" id="playButton">play</button>
    <span class="controlTime" id="currentTime">00:00</span>
    <div id="progressWrap">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="controlTime" id="fullDuration">00:00</span>
  </nav>

</div>
```